# Full Screen Custom Popover issue in iOS7 and iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I am developing an app for iPad only. In which in for one functionality i want to display **FullCustom Popover**.

For that my code is as below:-

```
DuplicateViewController *viewControllerForPopover =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DuplicatePopoverVC"];
    viewControllerForPopover.arr_studentDetail = self.arrStudentDetail;
    viewControllerForPopover.dictSelectedProg = dictSelectedProgram;

    self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                    initWithContentViewController:viewControllerForPopover];
    [self.popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    viewControllerForPopover.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [self.popover setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4]];
    [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.view.bounds inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
```

I set popover size and tried with other option but can't make it full screen.

**ViewDidLoad -> DuplicateViewController**

```
[view_main.layer setBorderWidth:5.0f];
[view_main.layer setCornerRadius:25.0f];
[view_main.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(29.0f/255.0f) green:134.0f/255.0f blue:140.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor];
```

But while running App, It display as below:-

[image]

Please help me to display full screen Popover. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: popovercontroller has limited minimum and maximum height and width beyond that the content size frame does not apply it will leave space about 20 points at all corners. i think it is for arrow . 
 As mentioned in popover.h file 
"This property allows direction manipulation of the content size of the popover. Changing the property directly is equivalent to animated=YES. The content size is limited to a minimum width of 320 and a maximum width of 600."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create two classes
the first one should inherit UIPopoverController
the second one should inherit UIPopoverBackgroundView

for example:

**CustomUIPopoverController.h**

```
@interface CustomUIPopoverController : UIPopoverController
```

**CustomUIPopoverController.m**

```
@implementation CustomUIPopoverController

- (id)initWithContentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    self = [super initWithContentViewController:viewController];
    if (self) {
        self.popoverBackgroundViewClass = [CustomUIClearPopoverBackgroundView class];
        [self setPopoverContentSize:viewController.view.frame.size];
    }
    return self;
}
```

@end

**CustomUIClearPopoverBackgroundView.h**

```
@interface CustomUIClearPopoverBackgroundView : UIPopoverBackgroundView
```

**CustomUIClearPopoverBackgroundView.m**

```
#import "CustomUIClearPopoverBackgroundView.h"

@implementation CustomUIClearPopoverBackgroundView

#pragma mark - no arrow

+ (CGFloat)arrowHeight {
    return 0;
}

+ (CGFloat)arrowBase {
    return 0;
}

- (CGFloat)arrowOffset {
    return 0;
}

- (void)setArrowOffset:(CGFloat)arrowOffset {

}

- (UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirection {
    return 0;
}

- (void)setArrowDirection:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirection {
}


#pragma mark - no margins

+ (UIEdgeInsets)contentViewInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}

#pragma mark - fully transparent (default is 0.15)

+(BOOL)wantsDefaultContentAppearance {

    return NO;
}

- (void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow {
    [super willMoveToWindow:newWindow];

    // hide shadow image view
    [self.superview.subviews[0] setHidden:YES];
}
@end
```

I used this but I don't like it very much.
the second option is to create a container view and hide/show it as you like.
this way it's a pure view controller and you don't need to mess with popup stuff
to create the transparency, make your container view background = clear, the view controller view background color = clear, and add a semi-transparent button in the size of the view controller for the semi-transparent black background. on click of the button close the window (= same effect as tapping the popup background)

Comment: I ll check and contact u soon.